# Ignore ssl signage when installing npm locally to let bower restore packages

Tags: node.js, ssl, bower

I'm trying to locally restore a .bower project. In order to do that I've installed Node.js and the next step is: npm install, this produces the following problem:

My collegue's solved this issue by setting the git config property [http] sslVerify to false.

But this doesn't help for me. We're also working behind a proxy, which has been configured in the .bowerrc file. So it should skip certificate verification entirely.

the .bowerrc file also has it's "strict-ssl" setting set on false.

The error says there is a self signed certificate:

```
[file location]>npm install    
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\n
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

npm ERR! self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

The full error log can be found in npm-debug.log the first error is at line 230: http://www.filedropper.com/npm-debug

I've also tried the command npm install -g bower, but it produces the same problem. According to the bower install guide I should be able to install Node.js and run npm install -g bower.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to [set the registry to http instead of https](https://stapp.space/fight-with-2/).

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```